# Apache files shown as index but not accessible

Tags: apache

I am having some trouble accessing files on Apache 2.4 running on Ubuntu.

The files that are inaccessible are being shown in the alias folder /static/.

[image]

When trying to access any of the items displayed I get the following message.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /static/abe.css was not found on this server.
```

The virtual host file for this looks like...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName explorer.htmlcoin.com
    Alias /static/ /home/explorer/HTMLCoinExplorer/HTMLCoin-Abe/htdocs
    Alias /robots.txt /home/explorer/HTMLCoinExplorer/HTMLCoin-Abe/htdocs/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/explorer/HTMLCoinExplorer/HTMLCoin-Abe/htdocs/favicon.ico
    Alias / /usr/lib/cgi-bin/abe.fcgi/

    # FcgidIOTimeout 40
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/explorer/HTMLCoinExplorer/HTMLCoin-Abe/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/explorer/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    # Uncomment to log Abe requests.
    ErrorLog /var/log/abe_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/abe_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check (fix) permission on files, in order to be readable/accessible to other (like is Apache user set in your configuration). Usually set read by others and execute/search by others. For example chmod 755 for directory, and 644 [ read by owner,  write by owner , read by group, read by others] for files. 
You can also change you setting for folder to:

```
<Directory /home/explorer/HTMLCoinExplorer/HTMLCoin-Abe/htdocs/>
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Just to test

Comment: Those files are set to 777 out of desperation and have www-data as group owner.

Comment: Tried with the same result :(

Comment: See again,  AllowOverride All

Comment: Same results. FYI I am restart Apache each time.

Link is here... http://explorer.htmlcoin.com/static/

Comment: I see, maybe your DocumentRoot is set wrong? just check your /var/log/apache2/error.log maybe we can get any clue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72210/discussion-between-user3344236-and-bushstar).

Comment: After adding the forward slash like in your example above to each instance of htdocs it now loads those files. When it was loading abe.css it was trying to access htdocsabe.css. Thanks for your help.